# Definition of the pullback of the sheaf of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I premise that I'm very new to the study of algebraic geometry so probably things that can look trivial are not so clear to me.

Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$, $g: Y\rightarrow Z$ be morphisms of schemes.

My goal is to show that this sequence is exact:

$ f^*\Omega_{Y/Z} \longrightarrow \Omega_{X/Z} \longrightarrow \Omega_{X/Y} \longrightarrow 0$

I read everywhere that I have to use the first fundamental exact sequence, i.e.:

$ \Omega_{B/A} \bigotimes_{B} C \longrightarrow \Omega_{C/A} \longrightarrow \Omega_{C/B} \longrightarrow 0 $

where $ A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C $ are morphisms of $A$-algebras.

Now, the first problem is that I'm not able to use the definition of the pullback in such a way to explicit the correct tensor product.

The second problem is that, even solving the first, it seems to me that the two sequences don't fit ( $A,B,C$ don't correspond to $X,Y,Z$) in the two sequences.

Comment: In an affine piece $X=\operatorname{Spec}C$, $Y=\operatorname{Spec}B$, $Z=\operatorname{Spec}A$ and ...

Comment: @user10354138 I'm still missing the point. Your answer in some sense solves my second doubt about the correspondence, even though I still have to accept that It can be reformulated in terms of the Specs. But, accepted that, I'm trying this explicit the first term of the sequence but I'm not sure It Is correct at this point, and in case it is I can't conclude. Here it is my attempt: $f^*\Omega_{Spec B/Spec A} = f^{-1}\Omega_{Spec B/Spec A} \bigotimes_{f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_Y(Spec C)}\mathscr{O}_X(Spec C) $.

Comment: @user10354138 Probably if I'm not wrong, it is sufficient to show that $ f^{-1}\Omega_{Spec B/Spec A}  \sim \Omega_{Spec B/Spec A} $ and that $ f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_Y(Spec C) \sim C$. How far am I?

Comment: That's exactly what you need to show, except that you should have $\Omega_{B/A}$ on the right side in your last comment. But that follows more or less by definition. You should also figure out why these local results in affine charts glue together to the global exact sequence of sheaves.

Comment: @IDC Please could you write explicitely what you mean when you say that follows more or less by definition?

Comment: The sheaf of differential forms on a scheme is defined in such a way that its restriction to an affine open subset $\mathrm{Spec}\ A$ is exactly the sheaf corresponding to the module of Kahler differentials over $A$.