# Sub-problem in the definition of the pullback of the sheaf of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

My question is a sub-problem I came up while trying to solve the question I proposed here ([Definition of the pullback of the sheaf of differentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765561/definition-of-the-pullback-of-the-sheaf-of-differentials)). But I resume it here anyway for completness:

Consider the morphism of schemes

$f: X \longrightarrow Y$

How can $f^*\Omega_{Y/Z}$ be explicited in terms of a tensor product ?

I hope the question makes sense even without the context given by the link, but I'm so far from understanding the question linked that I cannot even say if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question. This tensor product is coming from the definition of the pullback of a sheaf of modules.

If $f: X \to Y$ is a morphism of ringed spaces and $\mathcal{F}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module, then $f^* \mathcal{F}$ is *defined* to be $f^{-1}\mathcal{F} \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y} \mathcal{O}_X$, where $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is part of the data of $f$, and $f^{-1}$ is the usual pullback of sheaves.

In particular, if $f: \operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a morphism of schemes, and $\mathcal{F} = \tilde{M}$ then $f^*\mathcal{F} = \widetilde{M \otimes_AB}$ is the extension of scalars of $M$.

Edit: For completeness, let me link to a [proof in the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BJ) of the above fact.